# why the source code face detection that find from doc opencv dose'nt show any thing

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012, opencv3.0

hi my code here (according of docs opencv)

```
#include "opencv2/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
/* Function Headers */
void detectAndDisplay( Mat frame );
/* Global variables */
String face_cascade_name = "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";
String eyes_cascade_name = "haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml";
CascadeClassifier face_cascade;
CascadeClassifier eyes_cascade;
String window_name = "Capture - Face detection";
/* @function main */
int main( void )
    {
    VideoCapture capture;
    Mat frame;
    //-- 1. Load the cascades
    if( !face_cascade.load( face_cascade_name ) ){ printf("--(!)Error loading face cascade\n"); return -1; };
    if( !eyes_cascade.load( eyes_cascade_name ) ){ printf("--(!)Error loading eyes cascade\n"); return -1; };
    //-- 2. Read the video stream
    capture.open( -1 );
    if ( ! capture.isOpened() ) { printf("--(!)Error opening video capture\n"); return -1; }
    while (  capture.read(frame) )
        {
        if( frame.empty() )
            {
            printf(" --(!) No captured frame -- Break!");
            break;
            }
        //-- 3. Apply the classifier to the frame
        detectAndDisplay( frame );
        int c = waitKey(10);
        if( (char)c == 27 ) { break; } // escape
        }
    return 0;
    }
/* @function detectAndDisplay */
void detectAndDisplay( Mat frame )
    {
    std::vector<Rect> faces;
    Mat frame_gray;
    cvtColor( frame, frame_gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY );
    equalizeHist( frame_gray, frame_gray );
    //-- Detect faces
    face_cascade.detectMultiScale( frame_gray, faces, 1.1, 2, 0|CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );
    for( size_t i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++ )
        {
        Point center( faces[i].x + faces[i].width/2, faces[i].y + faces[i].height/2 );
        ellipse( frame, center, Size( faces[i].width/2, faces[i].height/2), 0, 0, 360, Scalar( 255, 0, 255 ), 4, 8, 0 );
        Mat faceROI = frame_gray( faces[i] );
        std::vector<Rect> eyes;
        //-- In each face, detect eyes
        eyes_cascade.detectMultiScale( faceROI, eyes, 1.1, 2, 0 |CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );
        for( size_t j = 0; j < eyes.size(); j++ )
            {
            Point eye_center( faces[i].x + eyes[j].x + eyes[j].width/2, faces[i].y + eyes[j].y + eyes[j].height/2 );
            int radius = cvRound( (eyes[j].width + eyes[j].height)*0.25 );
            circle( frame, eye_center, radius, Scalar( 255, 0, 0 ), 4, 8, 0 );
            }
        }
    //-- Show what you got
    }
```

i use pre-built opencv and my program not have any error but it dosn't work! it warning cant find PDB file,its for debugging and not influence in execution program. for not have this warning i go tools>options>debugger>checked microsoft symbol server warning now not have but it dosent work?!

where is problem??!!!!!!!11

Comment: I see that you are using Visual Studio on windows using a pre-built OpenCV package. Can you paste the output from the console (where you noticed the warnings about the PDB) after you click run?

Comment: i solve this warning but dosn't work?                                     'opencv.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'F:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'opencv.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'F:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'opencv.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'F:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'opencv.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'K:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin\opencv_world300.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

Answer (score 0):

finally i succeed,i first for PDB errors tools>option>debugging>outputwindow>moduleloadmessage >off and then i tools>option>debugging>symbols>microsoft symbols server not checked and then i chnge capture.open( -1 ); to capture.open( 0 ); now by seting in opencv itworks,thanks very much stackprogramer (just now)edit